# Is there a library for both Javascript and Rails to encrypt and decrypt with a key?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, encryption

I'd like to encrypt a string in the server side with a password, and decrypt it in the client side with the same password.

How to approach this?

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for some encryption functions. Using whichever method you want will do the job, as methods are standard and they all have implementations in most languages.

Take a look at [AES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) for example!

JS implementation: http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/

Ruby: https://gist.github.com/1077760